# My Python program it's not writing sql database

Tags: python, mysql

This is my code, i'm getting data from a MCP3008 and I want to write that values into a SQL Database, but it's not working. When I execute the code it's okay, but when I open the SQL Database it's empty.

Python Program:

```
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)


def ReadChannel(channel):
  adc = spi.xfer2([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
  data = ((adc[1]&3) << 8) + adc[2]
  return data

TIMES = 480

def AdcRead(adc_value = []):
    time_start = time.time()
    i = 0
    while True:
        time_current = time.time()
        if time_current > time_start + i / float(TIMES):
            print('{}: {}'.format(i, time_current))
            data = ReadChannel(0)
            adc_value.append(data)
            i += 1
        if i > 223:
            max_value = max(adc_value)
            break
    print(adc_value)
    return max_value

amp = AdcRead() * 0.8
amp = amp + 0.0
print("Binario: {}").format(amp)
output = 240*(amp/1024)*30
print("Potennia: {}").format(output)
amp_out = output/240
print ("Amperes: {}").format(amp_out)
output_h = output/3600
price = output_h * 0.15


ts = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime())
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","pass","auto_room_control")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO auto_room_control  VALUES ('%s', '%d', '%d', '%d', '%d' )", (ts, amp_out, output, output_h, price)
try:
   cursor.execute(sql)
   db.commit()
except:
   db.rollback()

db.close()
```

And when I execute the MySql command:

```
mysql> USE auto_room_control;
mysql> SELECT *  FROM power_consumption;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I get that "Empty set(0.00 sec)". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are silently ignoring the statement execution. Maybe that is throwing an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues.

1. Change

   ```
   sql = "INSERT INTO auto_room_control  VALUES ('%s', '%d', '%d', '%d', '%d' )", (ts, amp_out, output, output_h, price)
   try:
       cursor.execute(sql)
       db.commit()
   except:
       db.rollback()
   ```

   to

   ```
   sql = "INSERT INTO auto_room_control  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
   sqldata = (ts, amp_out, output, output_h, price)
   try:
      cursor.execute(sql, sqldata)
      db.commit()
   except:
      db.rollback()
   ```

   because the `%s` are interpreted by the database driver and that is the cleanest way to prevent SQL injection.
2. Change this to

   ```
   sql = "INSERT INTO auto_room_control  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
   sqldata = (ts, amp_out, output, output_h, price)
   with db as cursor:
      cursor.execute(sql, sqldata)
   ```

   The with statement does the committing and rolling back on its own.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO auto_room_control  VALUES ('%s', '%d', '%d', '%d', '%d' )", (ts, amp_out, output, output_h, price)
```

You should write this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO auto_room_control  VALUES ('%s', %d, %d, %d, %d )" % (ts, amp_out, output, output_h, price)
```

In the your case, you just create couple of string and another couple, instead of formatting.

Comment: Hmm, seems prone to SQL injection... And I don't think quotes are needed around numbers